# Can an Indian national (with a 2 years valid UK visa) visit Montenegro without visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, montenegro

I am an Indian national, and me and wife are going to the UK for a month. We have 2 years valid UK visa. Also we just spoke to our travel agent if we can visit some other countries without a visa for 1 week, and he recommend Montenegro.

He said we can visit Montenegro without a visa on 2 years UK visa. He said we can travel through Ryanair.

Before I buy tickets, I want to make sure if we need any visa.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes you can enter Montenegro with valid 2 years UK visit visa for up to 30 days without a visa The answer is from the official **Montenegro Ministry Of foreign Affairs** website:

http://www.mvpei.gov.me/en/sections/consular-affairs/visa-regimes-for-foreign-citizens/

> --- Overview of visa regimes for foreign citizens ---
>
> Holders of travel
>   documents containing a valid Schengen visa, a valid visa of the United
>   States of America, United Kingdom and Northern Ireland and the
>   Republic of Ireland, or a permission to stay in these countries, may
>   enter and stay, or pass through the territory of Montenegro up to 30
>   days, and not longer than the expiry of visa, if the period of
>   validity of the visa is less than 30 days.
>
> Holders of travel documents issued by the European Union Member States
>   or the United States of America, Kingdom of Norway, Republic of
>   Ireland, Swiss Confederation, Canada, Commonwealth of Australia, New
>   Zealand and Japan based on the Convention Relating to the Status of
>   Refugees (1951) or Convention Relating to the Status of Stateless
>   Persons (1954), as well as Travel Documents for Foreigners may enter,
>   pass through the territory of and stay in Montenegro up to 30 days
>   without a visa.
>
> Mere possession of a visa does not grant the entry to Montenegro.
>   Other legal requirements for granting a foreigner the entry and stay
>   to Montenegro must also be met according to the Law on Foreigners
>   (“Official Gazette of Montenegro”, no. 56/14 , 28/15 and 16/16.
>
> Visa regime between Montenegro and other countries is regulated by the
>   Decree on visa regime (“Official Gazette of Montenegro”, No. 35/16).
>
> Visa in itself does not offer a grant of permission to work in
>   Montenegro. Person who intends to work in Montenegro must obtain a
>   temporary residence permit for the purpose of employment or seasonal
>   work, on the grounds of previously issued work permit.

Also, the holder of an ordinary Indian passport needs a Montenegro visa:

> [image]

Comment: It appears that you have formatted your own text as block quotes.  This is unorthodox and (to me, at least) confusing.  Is there any chance you'd change it?

Comment: @phoog u mean mfa block letter

Comment: I mean the fact that you prefixed your text with `>` symbols.

Comment: @phoog, can you edit that. I would really appreciate

Comment: Okay,  I changed the formatting so the images are now block quotes and your text isn't.  It's better, however, to copy the text from the images so it's searchable.

Answer (score 10):

According to [TIMATIC](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/vendors/default.aspx?i=TIMATIC), that is correct, you do not require a visa to visit Montenegro when you are:

> Passengers with a visa, valid for the period of stay, issued by Ireland (Rep.), USA, United Kingdom or a Schengen Member State for a maximum stay of 30 days.

IATA Timatic is what airlines and travel agents use to verify passengers travel document requirements for destination and transit points.